# How to implement Bootstrap stateful button in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, button

So with bootstrap it seems pretty straightforward to implement a "Loading" state when clicking on a button, see link below (Stateful section):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-stateful

I did some research but wasn't able to find a straightforward to implement that in Angular thru the Angular Bootstrap UI lib. Any tips out there?

Answer (score 2):

You could just set the text, disabled state etc depending on if you're loading data or not. Something like this

```
<button ng-click="vm.clickAction()" ng-disabled="vm.loading" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    {{ vm.loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Click me!' }}
</button>
```

Then in the controller

```
.controller('TestController', function(someService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.loading = false;

  vm.clickAction = function() {
    vm.loading = true;
    someService.doSomething().then(function(someData) {
      vm.someData = someData; // optional
      vm.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We use something similar like this here:

https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy

Answer (score 1):

This changes the button's class to active and the text to "Loading" when `$scope.loading` is true:

```
<button ng-click="myClick()" ng-class="{active: loading}">
    <span ng-show="loading">Loading</span>
    <span ng-hide="loading">Submit</span>
</button>
```

Or, if you want the button to be disabled, use:

```
<button ng-click="myClick()" ng-disabled="loading">
    <span ng-show="loading">Loading</span>
    <span ng-hide="loading">Submit</span>
</button>
```

In your controller, add this function:

```
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.myClick = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    ... do something slow
    $scope.loading = false;
}
```